# how to attach a script to a button

Tags: python

I have a panel with 3 buttons and a script that they should execute. But the problem is that I can not connect the desired script with the button.

1. The script appends the desired character to the scene.
2. The second script should perform the render settings I need for my work. And I would like to stuff them into buttons

```py
file_path = 'D:/11.blend'
inner_path = 'Object'
object_name = 'Suzanne'
bpy.ops.wm.append( filepath=os.path.join(file_path, inner_path, object_name), directory=os.path.join(file_path, inner_path), filename=object_name )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps if you pasted the text of your Python code into your question I could give you specific instructions, but the general answer is that you need an [*Operator*](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html). It is a class that, among other things, has an `execute` function.  You would put the code to set your render settings or run your script into the execute function.  The manual has this simple example:

```py
class HelloWorldOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.hello_world"
    bl_label = "Minimal Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        print("Hello World")
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

The manual example shows using a menu to invoke the operator, but you could also do it from your [Panel](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html).  The technique for that is to assign the operator to an `operator` layout function.  The Panel manual entry also has an example of that.

Here's an example that puts that altogether.  It uses your commands from your comments; so it's not very general.  Usually one would make the input file and object setable, rather than hard code them.  All you need to do here is add your code for rendering where the comment is now.

```py
import bpy
import os
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.types import Panel

# https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260863/how-to-attach-a-script-to-a-button

file_path = 'D:/11.blend'
inner_path = 'Object'
object_name = 'Suzanne'


class TLA_OT_addmonkey(Operator):
    """ Add an object called Suzanne from a specific file """
    bl_idname = "tla.addmonkey"
    bl_label = "add Suzanne"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode == "OBJECT"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.wm.append(
                filepath=os.path.join(file_path, inner_path, object_name),
                directory=os.path.join(file_path, inner_path),
                filename=object_name
            )

        return {'FINISHED'}


class TLA_OT_setrender(Operator):
    """ Set the render properties """
    bl_idname = "tla.setrender"
    bl_label = "set render properties"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode == "OBJECT"

    def execute(self, context):
        # Put your render property code here
        return {'FINISHED'}

class TLA_PT_sidebar(Panel):
    """Sidebar"""
    bl_label = "Things to Do"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "TLA"

    def draw(self, context):
        col = self.layout.column(align=True)
        col.operator("tla.addmonkey")
        col.operator("tla.setrender")

 
classes = [
    TLA_OT_addmonkey,
    TLA_OT_setrender,
    TLA_PT_sidebar,
]

def register():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)


def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Comment: I need append 
import bpy
import os
 
file_path = 'D:/11.blend'
inner_path = 'Object'
object_name = 'Suzanne'
 
bpy.ops.wm.append(
    filepath=os.path.join(file_path, inner_path, object_name),
    directory=os.path.join(file_path, inner_path),
    filename=object_name
    )

Comment: @Welet put that script in your question rather than in a comment on my answer.  But basically you want to put that code, except the `import` statement in your Python where the `print` statement is above.  Perhaps you could benefit from watching the Scripting for Artist tutorials on YouTube?

Comment: I rarely write anything. On python, I need help with specific process automation
 I will be glad if you can give me the code for my task

Comment: @Welet StackExchange really isn't a forum for finding other people to do work for you. It's meant for asking specific questions when you you get stuck trying to solve a problem.  The script I added at the end already does 90+% of the work you've described.  All that's left is for you to figure out what render settings you want and stuff code to do that where the comment is in the code I gave you.

Comment: Thanks for the help^_^ and I will keep in mind while improving my python knowledge. I had everything ready except understanding how to fasten the script to the button. So thank you more

Comment: @Welet you're welcome.  Good luck with your script.

Comment: Hi, could you help me again? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261075/how-to-use-relative-paths-instead-of-absolute-ones