# How to use relative paths instead of absolute ones

Tags: python

I have an absolute path. But I need it to become relative. After reading a few articles and tried to do something myself. But I was powerless. :(
It's not the library that writes all the time. I can't figure out how to make a link with a relative path

```
bpy.ops.wm.link(
            filepath=os.path.join('Z:\\SuperRally\\assets\\characters\\alex\\alex_rig.blend', 'Collection', 'Alex_main'),
            directory=os.path.join('Z:\\SuperRally\\assets\\characters\\alex\\alex_rig.blend', 'Collection'),
            filename='Alex_main'
        )
```

It is work

```
directory = "//..\..\..\..\\assets\\characters\\higy\\higy_rig.blend\\Collection" bpy.path.relpath(directory) == directory bpy.ops.wm.link(directory=bpy.path.abspath(directory), filename="Higy_main")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with `bpy.ops.wm.link`, you need to rely on the function itself to store the path in your blend file as a relative path.  Fortunately it does that by default because it has a keyword argument `relative_path` that defaults to `True`.

First, you don't need the `filepath` keyword argument.

Second, you need to create a directory entry string.  You can do this by starting with a relative path like `//relative_path_to_file.blend`.

Finally you need to add a "directory" to this string.  This is the section of the file that you want to take your link from.  In my example, I'm going to link a material, so I need to add `/Material`.

- /blender
- /blender/work <-  the directory my current file is saved in
- /blender/stuff <- the directory that the file I want to link to is in.

I can write this code to get a path relative name:

```py
directory = "//../stuff/src.blend/Material"
```

but `bpy.ops.wm.link` needs an absolute path, so I use `bpy.path.abspath()` to convert it.  The call to `bpy.ops.wm.link` looks like this:

```py
bpy.ops.wm.link(directory=bpy.path.abspath(directory), filename="ShinyRed")
```

where `"ShinyRed"` is the name of the material I want to link to.

putting it all together gives:

```py
directory = "//../stuff/src.blend/Material"
bpy.ops.wm.link(directory=bpy.path.abspath(directory), filename="ShinyRed")
```

and when I check *Libraries* in the outliner under *Blender File* display mode, I see that I am given a relative path name.

Since you have absolute paths, I should assure you that you'll still end up with a relative path if you do this:

```py
bpy.ops.wm.link(directory='Z:\\SuperRally\\assets\\characters\\alex\\alex_rig.blend\\Collection',
            filename='Alex_main')
```

and, again, you don't need the `filepath` argument.

Comment: it seems i won
directory = "//..\..\..\..\\assets\\characters\\higy\\higy_rig.blend\\Collection"
bpy.path.relpath(directory) == directory
bpy.ops.wm.link(directory=bpy.path.abspath(directory), filename="Higy_main")

Comment: I came up with this while analyzing your answer

Answer (score 1):

#### Get path of current opened blend file

```
import bpy
p = bpy.data.filepath

if p == "":
    print("unsaved file")
else:
    print(p)
```

#### Go back

```
bpy.path.abspath("//../hello.blend")
#to go back a directory
```

#### Make all paths to external files relative to current .blend

```
bpy.ops.file.make_paths_relative()
```

#### Link .blend file

```
import bpy

filepath = "//file.blend"

# link all objects
with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=True, relative=True) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.objects = [name for name in data_from.objects]
```

Comment: It's not the library that writes all the time. I can't figure out how to make a link with a relative path

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work? `bpy.path.relpath()` is builtin, seems one-and-done.

```
bpy.data.filepath
>>> '/home/jake/Documents/blender/projects/test.blend'

fp = bpy.data.filepath

bpy.path.relpath(fp)
>>> '//test.blend'
```

Comment: It is wok. directory = "//..\..\..\..\\assets\\characters\\higy\\higy_rig.blend\\Collection" bpy.path.relpath(directory) == directory bpy.ops.wm.link(directory=bpy.path.abspath(directory), filename="Higy_main")